# Dynamically Generated HTML downloaded from cach in MVC application?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

We have developed MVC application, Here we have one functionality export to HTML. When user clicks the "Export to html" button then we have generated the HTML file with that user name. this html file contains the invoice details. we have maintained only one file for one user, replaced the invoice information alone, instead of creating new file.

We have generated the HTML file in controler class and uploaded into server, the below jQuery to view the generated html file.

```
if (dropDownSelect == 'To HTML File') {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Appointment/CreateHTMLInvoice/",                 //here we have called the controller and create the html file.
                cache: false,
                data: {
                    AppID: ShareAppID,
                    CusIDs: SelectedCusIDs,
                    CustFlag: AllCustomerFlag
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result != null) {                      
                        window.open('', $.now()).location.href = result;        ///After successfully created the HTML file, here is the code to view the html file
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert('Error ' + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
```

First time it is downloaded the correct file,  from second time it is downloaded the previous file instead of new one until clear the browser cache. I have checked in server file, this file is new one, we don't know why the application again and again download the same file which one we have generated first time .

Please advise to clear the cache. we need to view the new file for every click.

Answer (score 0):

Put a question mark at the end of the URL to bust cache

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Note: Setting cache to false will only work correctly with HEAD and
>   GET requests.

Is there a reason this is a POST request?  It looks like it could very easily be a GET and then your `cache: false` will work correctly.